# How to stop my touch event from firing when users swipe iPhone screen

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios7.1

This is part of my iPhone weather widget.

My touch event seems to work fine, i.e when the user taps the touch area everything does what it should, the problem is when the user swipes the screen (to go to next springboard page) it swipes ok but the swipe also triggers my touch event.

How can I stop the native swipe from firing my touch event?

Thank you for any help.

BTW, "touch" is my defined touch area and "ChangeToClick" just makes it workable on the Mac/PC.

```
function init() {
    if ((EnableTouch == true) && (AnimationsOnly == false)) {
StartTouch();
}

if (ChangeToClick == false) { var touchmode = "touchend"; } else { var touchmode = "click"; }

function StartTouch() {
document.getElementById("touch").addEventListener(touchmode, touchAnimation, false);
}

var forecastdisplay = true;
var hourlyForecastDisplay = false;

function touchAnimation() {
    if (forecastdisplay == false) {
    document.getElementById("forecastContainer").className = "scaleNormal";
    document.getElementById("hourlyForecastContainer").className = "scaleZero";
    document.getElementById('WeatherInfoContainer').className = "normal";
    document.getElementById('clockContainer').className = "normal";
    document.getElementById('goldClockGlass').className = "normal";
    document.getElementById('goldClockRing').className = "normal";
    document.getElementById('sunriseSunsetGlass').className = "normal";
    document.getElementById('fullmoon').className = "normal";
    forecastdisplay = true;
    hourlyForecastDisplay = false;
}else{

    document.getElementById("forecastContainer").className = "scaleZero";
    document.getElementById("hourlyForecastContainer").className = "scaleNormal";
    document.getElementById('WeatherInfoContainer').className = "moveUp";
    document.getElementById('clockContainer').className = "moveUp";
    document.getElementById('goldClockGlass').className = "moveUp";
    document.getElementById('goldClockRing').className = "moveUp";
    document.getElementById('sunriseSunsetGlass').className = "moveUp";
    document.getElementById('fullmoon').className = "scaleZero";
    forecastdisplay = false;
    hourlyForecastDisplay = true;
    }    
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Just a wild guess without knowing it for touch events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation in your swipe event

Comment: Hi, I don't have a swipe event, it's just the native swipe in iOS, I also don't know the exact name given to a swipe in order to stop it.